# Is $(Nb)^{o(N)}=e$, where $N$ is a normal subgroup of group $G$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of group $G$. Let $Nb\in G/H$ be a coset, where $b\notin N$. Herstein says that $(Nb)^{o(N)}=e$, where $o(N)$ is the order of the subgroup $N$. I don't understand why. Shouldn't $(Nb)^{o(G/N)}=e$?

Comment: I think so. In $\mathbf A_3 \unlhd \mathbf S_3$, the unique coset consists of $3$ involutions so in this case $(Nb)^3 = Nb$.

Answer (score 0):

In this proof it is probably assumed that $b^{o(N)}=e$. In that case $(Nb)^{o(N)} = N(b^{o(N)}) = Ne = N$, which is the identity element in $G/N$.